# Better performance with predicate or hierarchy XPath in XSLT template match

Tags: xslt-1.0

I will be using a lot of `<xsl:template match="">` and I want to order them so they are easy to read and debug.

While putting the attribute or the element at the start of the match="" will make it easy to know which node I am applying, it would be a mess if I need to add more hierarchy nodes.

So I want to know will there be any performance differences between the 2 approaches please.

```
<xsl:template match="@Text[contains(., 'Hi') and parent::InputBox/parent::Message]">
```

or

```
<xsl:template match="Message/InputBox/@Text[contains(., 'Hi')]">
```

Comment: The answer depends on whether you have Text attributes that are not a grandchild of a Message node.  If there are many of them, then the second case is more efficient.  Because it limits the number of Text attributes checked to those within Message nodes.  If all Text attributes are grandchildren of the Message node, I would be interest to hear what other people have to say.

Comment: Hi @Bluewood66 so assuming we have Text attribute at every element and have these templates: `<xsl:template match="Message"><xsl:apply-template select="@Text"/></xsl:template>`  and  `<xsl:template match="InputBox"><xsl:apply-template select="@Text"/></xsl:template>`.  Will these apply-template still try to match the first example?

Comment: Yes.  They both will match the first example.  (If you have a debugger, you can verify this by stepping through your code.)  So, you will unnecessarily be going to the first @Text template when applying templates for Message nodes.  That said, without the larger context of seeing the XML or your code I can't recommend an approach.

Comment: OK, so XSLT will match at the node and the hierarchies before the predicates. :) I will stick with the second example then.  Thanks